# Ordenar array de forma incomum

Tags: java, lista, classificação, arraylist, enums

Preciso ordenar uma lista em uma ordem que não segue nenhuma lógica entre os objetos, exemplo:

Minha lista:

```
[1,5,5,2,3,1,4,5,2,3]
```

Resultado esperado depois de ordenar:

```
[2,2,4,1,1,5,5,5,3,3]
```

Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Comment: E qual é o critério pra ordenar?

Comment: O critério é o seguinte: o cliente quer que a ordem de uma lista de itens seja todos os itens do tipo 2 primeiro, em seguida os itens do tipo 4, depois os itens do tipo 1, depois tipo 5 e depois tipo 3, porém não posso editar os enums, pois eles são classificações e estão no banco dessa forma, mas preciso mostrar esses itens num relatório nessa ordem específica (2, 4, 1, 5 e 3)

Comment: Se a quantidade de valores possíveis for pequena, talvez dê para usar um `Map` que contém a ordem de cada um, algo assim: https://ideone.com/C3KOLO

Answer (score -2):

Pensei em uma solução assim, mas ela também pode ser adaptada para objetos ou enums:

Java:

```java
    private static final List<Long> RIGHT_ORDER = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L));

    public List<Long> sort(List<Long> list) {
        List<Long> result = new ArrayList<>();
        RIGHT_ORDER.forEach(type -> result
                .addAll(list.stream().filter(item -> Objects.equals(type, item)).collect(Collectors.toList())));
        return result;
    }
```

**ATENÇÃO**: Fica uma ressalva, em `RIGHT_ORDER` precisa conter **todos** os "tipos" de objeto que você deseja ordenar, caso ele não esteja ali o item não será colocado no resultado.